# Can I have a NSStepper without max?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, interface-builder, nsstepper

In IB you can configure min and max for a NSStepper, but... what about if I don't want to limit the user with a max value. Can I do it? How?

[image]

Comment: Set the Maximum value to a really big number.

Answer (score 0):

There is no thing in computers "without max". Each property has it's own data type. In case of `NSStepper` it's double. Double can have it's maximum value depending on the number of bits used to store (this is platform dependent) [Read here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/fundamental-types-cpp?view=vs-2017). Double typically uses 8 bytes (64bits to store). So double has it's own maximum because it is limited to 64bits. It's maximum value is `DBL_MAX`. Exact explanation of exact number is an advanced topic of floating point data representation on computer.

Enough theory. Assign in code to maxValue DBL_MAX. In case compiler protests add float.h header

```
#include float.h

NSStepper *myStepper;
myStepper.maxValue = DBL_MAX;
```

NSStepper:

```
@interface NSStepper : NSControl <NSAccessibilityStepper> {
  @private
    unsigned int _reserved1;
    unsigned int _reserved2;
    unsigned int _reserved3;
    unsigned int _reserved4;
}

@property double minValue;

@property double maxValue;

@property double increment;

@property BOOL valueWraps;

@property BOOL autorepeat;

@end
```